# Understand flag setting

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, environment-variables, variable-expansion

I am trying to install BerkeleyDB STL .
I ran the following code to download n install the same

```
curl -OL http://download.oracle.com/berkeley-db/db-6.2.23.NC.tar.gz
tar xf db-6.2.23.NC.tar.gz
cd db-6.2.23.NC/build_unix
../dist/configure --prefix=$HOME --enable-stl
make
make install
```

then for further installation of my application i need to tell R where is BerkeleyDB STL, for which I did as stated by the manual :

```
CPPFLAGS=-I${HOME}/include
LDFLAGS=-L${HOME}/lib -Wl,-rpath=${HOME}/lib
```

But I get the following error while running the second command :

```
bash: -Wl,-rpath=/home/mayankmodi/lib: No such file or directory
```

even though the directory structure is

```
.
├── bin
├── env
├── include
├── lib
└── Videos
*I have deleted most of my folders to make it easy to spot lib directory
```

**QUESTION**: I need to understand the implication of

```
LDFLAGS=-L${HOME}/lib -Wl,-rpath=${HOME}/lib
```

Comment: [Always use quotes](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes)

Comment: @Cong Ma, that isn't creating the error though. Thanks for showing me the better practice however.

Comment: Lack of quotes definitely is causing the error. If you have another error after fixing the quotes, post it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
LDFLAGS=-L${HOME}/lib -Wl,-rpath=${HOME}/lib
```

with the `HOME` variable expanded, becomes

```
LDFLAGS=-L/home/mayankmodi/lib -Wl,-rpath=/home/mayankmodi/lib [rest of actual command]
```

which is interpreted as something close to

```
EnvironmentVariable=Value command line ...
```

i.e. Bash interprets the text `-Wl,-rpath=/home/mayankmodi/lib` as the start of a command or path to an executable, and attempts to run it with the environment variable setting `LDFLAGS=-L/home/mayankmodi/lib`, which fails because there's no such command or program.

To fix this, you can wrap the value to be given to `LDFLAGS` in double quotes:

```
LDFLAGS="-L${HOME}/lib -Wl,-rpath=${HOME}/lib"
```

so that `LDFLAGS` expands to the desired text.